# Swift SCNNode subclass hittest always returns SCNNode *not* subclass

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a subclass "ExSCNNode" of SCNNode to add more properties and behavior to the SCNNode.

```
class ExSCNNode : SCNNode {
...
}
```

I than build a scene with a  ExSCNNode.

```
let testnode = ExSCNNode()
```

When hittesting the scene:

```
// check what nodes are tapped
let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])

// check that we clicked on at least one object
if hitResults.count > 0 {

for hit in hitResults {
let hitnode = hit.node
...
```

hitnode is a SCNNode not a ExSCNNode.
But I want to get the ExSCNNode to access the advance functionality.

How do I get access to the subclass instead of the SCNNode class ?

Comment: You need to create it as an `ExSCNNode`. You have not included the code where it is created.

Comment: I create a scene of ExSCNodes. Just one in the example above added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast the object to your subclass:

```
// check what nodes are tapped
let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])

for hit in hitResults {
    if let hitnode = hit.node as? ExSCNNode {

        …
    }
```

Comment: extensions wont allow stored properties directly

Comment: This doesn't work you I cannot cast the node that was tapped to a custome node type!....

Comment: @BenSmith The hit test will always return the node containing the geometry, so make sure that your custom subclass is the node with the geometry attatched